# EXC_I386_IBT when setting CollectionViewCell to custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that I am trying to add GIFs to in each cell pulled from a site.  When I have the cell set to a standard UICollectionViewCell I get no issue, but when I run the code setting the cell to my subclass, I get `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error`.  Anyone have any experience with this error?

Relevant codeblock below, with the working code commented.  I should mention that the app doesn't crash, simply hits a break.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as GIFCell //issue here

    //var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


    // Configure the cell
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you register your custom cell class to UICollectionView? If yes, then it should be no problem, if not, try adding:

```
collectionView?.registerClass(GIFCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "GIFCellIdentifier");
```

Place it inside viewDidLoad() or init()